# App crashes when navigating to activity with ObjectBox Box object

Tags: objectbox

My app crashes when I login via the login activity and navigates to the MainActivity.  The MainActivity has an ObjectBox Box object reference on the OnCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //ObjectBox Box object reference for the BookEntity class 
    BoxStore boxStore = ((App) getApplication()).getBoxStore();
    bookBox = boxStore.boxFor(BookEntitiy.class);

    //bind views using butterknife
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    //reference the BookViewModel ViewModel
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BookViewModel.class);

    //call method
    observeViewModel();
}
```

When I remove or comment the Box object reference code the app navigates to the MainActivity.java activity correctly without crashing.

What could be causing this?

stacktrace:

04/05 14:23:47: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht.Home.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 30637 on device huawei-huawei_vns_l23-GVYHP17607000187
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.novo0007.gfbtestarcht-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30637 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Comment: You really should provide a stack trace of the "crash".

Comment: Please learn about Java exception stack traces and post it.

Answer (score 0):

I got through with the issue.  The database setup and configuration of ObjectBox on the website  were not very clear and step by step.  I had to go through a video tutorial of Objectbox on Udemy to get the setup right.  Please create legible tutorials/documentation on setting up ObjectBox correctly especially with the gradle files and manifest.xml etc.  Thanks.